# Geometry data (geoJSON) is not showing up in my Geoserver layer (connected to Mongo)

Tags: mongodb, geoserver

Currently running Geoserver 2.15. I have a Mongo database with GeoJSON location data. I can connect to my Mongo database using the gt-mongo plugin, and I have run a 2dsphere index over my geometry data. The layer shows up and I have published it through Geoserver, however when I look at the KML/GML/GeoJSON output (from layer preview) the geometry data is not there. Geoserver instead says that the geometry field is 'null', even though I know there is data there.

Mongo Document (relevant geometry fields):

```
'feature_collection': {
    'features: [ {
         'geometry': { "type":"Point", 
         'coordinates: [-1.3696973576336684, 51.828414753283056]
    } ]
}
```

The geometry field contains both "Point" and "Polygon" types, and may also be empty depending on the document.

Schema file that Geoserver produced when I added the layer:

```
    "typeName" : "location" ,
    "userData" : {
        "collection" : "location"} ,
    "geometryDescriptor" : {
        "localName" : "feature_collection.features.geometry" ,
         "crs" : {
              "type" : "name" ,
               "properties" : {
                   "name" : "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG:4326"}}} ,
    "attributeDescriptors" : [

        { "localName" : "extended_data.feature_collection.features.geometry" ,
        "type" : {
            "binding" : "org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry"} ,
        "userData" : {
            "encoding" : "GeoJSON" ,
            "mapping" : ".feature_collection.features.geometry"}
        }]
    }
```

How can I get GeoServer to show/recognize the geometry data that is in my database?

Comment: You might have invalid geometries, from the [docs](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/data/mongodb.html) 
"Self-intersecting polygons is a common data problem preventing MongoDBDataStore from functioning. Please note that self-intersection may arise due to the transformation to WGS84 coordinates (which is a necessary preliminary step for importing data into MongoDB), even if they did not exist in the original dataset."

Comment: I'm not seeing any errors when I run the index/add the layer though, or in the server logs when I ask for the GML output. From what I've seen those errors tend to pop up when adding or inspecting the layer.

Comment: Could this be related to the fact that the 'features' is an array of geometry points instead of one single geometry feature? The plugin does seem to have some issues recognizing other properties from my database in that format.

Comment: You should probably convert that to a multipoint rather than an array

Comment: Sorry, I think that was unclear. It's wouldn't be a multipoint, the 'features' level Mongo field is an array of embedded documents that may contain, for instance, both a 'point' geometry and then a 'polygon' geometry. It's already a geojson Feature Collection

Comment: possibly, I'm not a mongo user